# If $N=aP+R$ and $P=bQ+S$, show that $\cfrac{N}{ab}=aS+R$?

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading Chrystal's: *Algebra, An elementary text-book*:

> [image]

I tried to write $N=aP+R$ and $P=bQ+S$ (with the $Q$ inserted somewhat *artificially*) and then, making the substitutions:

$$N=a(bQ+S)+R=abQ+aS+R$$

Multiplying by $\cfrac{1}{ab}$:

$$\cfrac{N}{ab}=Q+\frac{S}{b}+\cfrac{R}{ab}$$

I've tried a lot of substitutions and couldn't show it. Could you give me some hint about it?

Comment: You don't have to show that $aS+R$ is the quotient, but the remainder. $Q$ is the actual quotient. All you have to show is that $aS+R < ab$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last equation, after multiplying by $ab$ you have $N=Qab+(aS+R).$ Now also $R<a$ [so also $R \le a-1$] and $S<b$ [so also $S \le b-1$] since they were defined as the remainders of the two division algorithm applications. So $aS+R \le a(b-1)+a-1=ab-1$ which is what you need for remainder on division by $ab.$